# How to upload file to azure blob storage?

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, cqrs, mediator

So I am tasked to create an endpoint that uploads file to Azure blob container. Here's my function app:

```
[FunctionName("UploadFileFunction")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = null)]
        UploadFileCommand cmd)
    {
        return await _httpFunctionExecutor.ExecuteAsync(async () =>
        {
            var res = await _mediator.Send(cmd);
            return new OkObjectResult(res);
        });
    }
```

here's the upload command class

```
public partial class UploadFileCommand : IRequest<Guid>
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public string FileLocation { get; set; }
}

public class UploadFileCommandHandler : IRequestHandler<UploadFileCommand, Guid>
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
    private readonly BlobServiceClient _blobServiceClient;

    public UploadFileCommandHandler(IConfiguration configuration, BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
        _blobServiceClient = blobServiceClient;
    }

    public async Task<Guid> Handle(UploadFileCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var id = Guid.Parse(request.Id);

        var containerName = _configuration.GetConnectionString("ContainerName");
        var uniqueFileName = $"{id }/{request.FileName}";

        var blobContainer = _blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);
        var blobClient = blobContainer.GetBlobClient(uniqueFileName);

        using FileStream uploadFileStream = File.OpenRead(@request.FileLocation);
        await blobClient.UploadAsync(uploadFileStream);
        uploadFileStream.Close();

        return id;
    }
}
```

In my local it runs fine, but when this is deployed Im getting an error "Could not find file". I think when deployed, its looking on the server side and not the client side..

Can I upload using byte or stream? which way can solve my problem? Thanks!

URL: https://myfunction.azurewebsites.net/api/UploadFileFunction

Sample payload:

```
{
    "Id": "a7a27e78-2523-452f-99ba-8631d4979505",
    "FileName": "test.jpg",
    "FileLocation": "C:\\temp\\test.jpg"
}
```

Comment: `I think when deployed, its looking on the server side and not the client side.` - This is exactly the case. You can read the file on the client side as byte array and pass that byte array to your Function.

Comment: Thanks @GauravMantri, do you have a working example on how to achieve this?

Comment: Can you please edit your question and include the client side code?

Comment: I dont think its needed. I just pass in the body. see updated question

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace GlobalTestting
{
    public class AzureBlob
    {
        private readonly BlobServiceClient _blobService;
        BlobContainerClient _blobContainer;
        public AzureBlob()
        {
            _blobService = new BlobServiceClient("connectionstring");
        }
        public bool Delete(string fileName)
        {
            try
            {
                _blobContainer = _blobService.GetBlobContainerClient("fileShareName");
                BlobClient blobClient = _blobContainer.GetBlobClient(fileName);
                blobClient.Delete();
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                return false;
            }
        }
        public void Upload(IFormFile file)
        {
            if (file.Length > 0)
            {
                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                var fileType = Path.GetExtension(fileName);
                var newFileName = String.Concat(Convert.ToString(Guid.NewGuid()), fileType);

                _blobContainer = _blobService.GetBlobContainerClient("fileShareName");
                _blobContainer.CreateIfNotExists();
                _blobContainer.SetAccessPolicy(PublicAccessType.BlobContainer);

                BlobClient blobClient = _blobContainer.GetBlobClient(newFileName);

                using Stream stream = file.OpenReadStream();
                blobClient.Upload(stream);
                var fileUrl = blobClient.Uri.AbsoluteUri;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This way you can install or delete it.